# If/else in htaccess breaks inner URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm forcing https and stripping www via .htaccess:

```
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This works perfectly. However, we need to force www for visitors from certain IPs (long story). To accomplish this, I did:

```
    <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} = '1.2.3.4' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '5.6.7.8' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '9.10.11.12' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '13.14.15.16.17'">   
        #Force www and force HTTPS for internal network traffic
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    </If>
    <Else>
        #Strip www and force HTTPS for public traffic
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    </Else>
```

This works. Visitors from the specified IPs are forced to https://www.example.com, while all other traffic gets the standard https://example.com. The homepage returns 200 OK. However, it makes all inner pages return 404 Not Found.

The entire "broken" .htaccess is below. examdiff confirms that the only difference between this and the working version is in the presence of the if/else condition.

The site runs Laravel 5.4, on a Digital Ocean LAMP droplet.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} = '99.31.174.113' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '12.112.227.153' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '12.0.107.10' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} = '50.240.55.141'">  
        #Force www and force HTTPS for internal network traffic
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    </If>
    <Else>
        #Strip www and force HTTPS for public traffic
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    </Else>


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"

    # Add correct content-type for fonts
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
    AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg

    # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
```

And here's the  entry for this site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public   
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /var/www/html/public
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The `000-default-le-ssl.conf` and `default-ssl.conf` are similar.

It seems that this section of .htaccess may not be executing:

```
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Could this be what is causing all inner pages to return 404 when I use the if/else conditions? Is it somehow terminating the execution of the subsequent lines in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block?

Answer (score 0):

Never could identify the issue, but solved by getting rid of the `<If>` `<Else>` block. Result:

```
#Force www and force HTTPS for internal network traffic
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.89 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.90 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.91 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]                


#Strip www and force HTTPS for public traffic
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.90
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.91    
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```